# How can I make a CMakeList.txt belong to certain target or a folder?

Tags: cmake

I give the following example to illustrate my question. The projects have the following structure:

```
CMakeLists.txt
Dir1
Dir2
Dir3
```

In the CMakeLists.txt, I have the following definitions:

```
macro(obtain_sublist result _curdir)
  set(curdir ${${_curdir}})
  FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*)
  SET(dirlist "")


  FOREACH(child ${children})
    IF(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
        LIST(APPEND dirlist ${child})
    ENDIF()
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${result} ${dirlist})
endmacro()

set(curDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
obtain_sublist(subdir curDir)
foreach(var ${subdir})
    add_subdirectory(${var})
endforeach()
```

Within each subdirectories (`Dir1, Dir2 and Dir3`) targets are built. When the project was built with Visual Studio, I can clearly observe that each target as well as its corresponding CMakeLists.txt, which is used to create the target. However, the top CMakeLists.txt in this example is unseen in the project as it does not create any target. Is there a way to include this CMakeLists.txt in the project? If possible, can I put it in a certain folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already appear in the `ALL_BUILD` target I think.

If you want, you can create a custom target just to hold it.  In the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(CMakeFiles SOURCES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)
```

Or you could add it to an existing target in one or more or the subdirs.  So, in a subdir CMakeLists.txt you could add:

```
add_executable(Dir1 dir1.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)
```

You can create sub-folders of the target in the VS solution (which need not relate to actual filesystem folders) by using [`source_group`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/source_group.html):

```
source_group("root" FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)
```